# Unable to access site locally, others can

Tags: apache, hosting

I run apache locally, on one of my homeservers. I am able to access the domain once or twice, but then it will time out. It simply wont allow me to access it from my ip (the same IP the site is hosted on). Others are able to type in the domain name, and access the server as much as they want. If i use a proxy, then i am also able to access it. The only times it messes up is when i try to access it without a vpn, or by using another computer that is on the network.

TL;DR cant access site from own network, other networks can access.

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us what operating system you use? It could also be that in the rules for that directory you are allowing access to it from any IP except localhost.

Example:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/> 
  Order Deny,Allow 
  Deny from 127.0.0.1 
  Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Such a configuration would deny everything from `localhost` and allow everything from any other IP.

Comment: debian 10, buster.

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  ServerName site.com
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Can you show the full content of the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf `?

Comment: Look good. When you PING to `site.com` or `subdomain.site.com` from `localhost` do you get a response? `?

Comment: yes. it worked from multiple computers, several times in a row. ive also tried other browsers but that didnt work.